# OpenCart Multiple Upload

Tags: php

i have a problem here , i build a simple multiple upload function on opencart , file save on folder but not save path n mysql ,can anyone help me ,

View :

```
       <input type="file" name="picture[]" accept="img/*" />
       <input type="file" name="picture[]" accept="img/*" />
```

Controller :

```
foreach ($this->request->files['picture']['error'] as $key => $error) {                   
        $tmp_name = $this->request->files['picture']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $this->request->post['img'] = "test/".$this->request->files['picture']['name'][$key];
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,DIR_IMAGE .$this->request->post['img']);
    }
```

Model :

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET image = '" . $this->db->escape($data['img']) . "',product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

Comment: What error do you get for the MySQL query?  It might help to show more context.

Comment: Casting as an int then saving as a string? ...(int)$product_id

Comment: Mike Brant : mysql no error ,but it only save 1 image , i upload 2 image,it only save the 2nd image in mysql ,i think my controller problem .

Comment: i echo  $this->request->post['img'];and it show a.jpg2.jpg , in mysql it only save 2.jpg . in folder it save 2 image.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create(){
        global $database;
        if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])){
            $data = $_FILES["fupload"]["error"];
            // loops through shops that has been selected and store category associated with store
            foreach ($_FILES["fupload"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
                //checks if there is no error
              if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'][$key],"../public/gallery/".basename($_FILES['fupload']['name'][$key]));
                $image = new Imageresize(); // an instance of image resize object
                $image->load("../public/gallery/".basename($_FILES['fupload']['name'][$key]));
                //$image->image =;
                $image->resize(400,400);
                $image->save("../public/gallery/".basename($_FILES['fupload']['name'][$key]));

                //this section is needed to get the extension for image type in renaming the image
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/gif"){
                    $ext = ".gif";
                }
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/png"){
                    $ext = ".png";
                }
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/jpeg"){
                    $ext = ".jpeg";
                }
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/pjpeg"){
                    $ext = ".jpeg";
                }
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/gif"){
                    $ext = ".gif";
                }
                if ($_FILES['fupload']['type'][$key]=="image/jpg"){
                    $ext = ".jpg";
                }
                $new_name = uniqid()."_".time().$ext; //new name for the image
                rename("../public/gallery/".basename($_FILES['fupload']['name'][$key]),"../public/gallery/".$new_name);
                $photo = $new_name;
                $sqlImg = "INSERT INTO gallery (img_url) VALUES ('$photo') ";

                        $Result = $database->db_query($sqlImg);

              }
            }
        }
    }
```

you can check out this code i used imageresize to resize the uploaded images and overwrite you may skip that section and just follow the loop for uploaded images

Comment: this look nice, where can i place this code to test? in open cart 1.5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Weeks ago I modified the current OpenCart last version (2.0.1.1) to support multiple images upload using DropZone.js. I'm doing public this project so you can download files from here:
https://github.com/oscaralderete/opencart-multiple-image-uploader